# How i can make more fluent walk animation

Tags: animation, rigify

i,m beginner and i,m try make a walk cycle animation but the problem is this

https://imgur.com/HrPIeOX

The animation doesn't look fluid at all and I don't know how to improve it.

[image]

I use a pose every 5 seconds, but try every 10 and it still comes out the same,

[image]

Comment: Using the graph editor is really helpful for animations.  It's available under the 'Animation' workspace on the top right, or you can just change your timeline to a graph editor.

Comment: Use a walk cycle reference like this one: https://idearocketanimation.com/app/uploads/2010/07/bcc574b7d45926758b92e89bd4c0160d.jpg

Comment: It's also helpful to duplicate all the keyframes at frame 1 with Ctrl-D then drag them to one frame past the last frame of the sequence (41 in your case). This should get rid of the jump as the sequence starts again.

Comment: pls provide blend file, then we can help you specifically to your problem

Comment: @Chris how do I do that?

Comment: open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: @Chris ready i upload the file